# Original code from matplotlib site not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I tried to run the code from this site:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py

And, its not work. I mean i downloaded the code to my computer which is windows 10.
I have python 3.7, and this code simply do nothing.
Any help!?
Thanks in ahead.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. It's lacking the final  `plt.show()` every python script needs that intends to show a matplotlib figure.

Comment: Will be [fixed soon](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/15217).